# UINavigationBar with two buttons on the left

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I know that on stackoverflow there are many similar questions but mine is a little different.
I'll show this with images, because it's easier to understand.
Using this code I took from
[here](http://www.mattdipasquale.com/blog/2010/11/02/how-to-add-multiple-uibarbuttonitems-to-uinavigationbar/), I had this result:

[image: some problems here]

It's easy to see that the second button isn't all on the screen.
I tried to but negative numbers in the `UIToolbar` frame but they don't work. I don't need any title there, only a way to move these buttons to the left.

Comment: Check this seems me the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789283/adding-uitoolbar-with-two-uibarbuttonitem-to-a-uinavigationbar-poor-uitoolbar-an

Comment: Does the same happen if you change your previous controller title to say just *Exams* instead of *Blood Exams*? I curious because I think the issue lies with the width of the button on the left, and the width of the `UIToolBar` you've created to house the extra two buttons.

Comment: '*There are many questions but this one is mine*'. Sorry, couldn't resist ;)

Comment: @edo42, I like the codes you provide.

Comment: @Toro but they don't work as I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a different approach. I created a [custom segmented control](https://github.com/j4n0/jobsket/blob/master/sources/main/ui/search/jobs/detail/SegControlVC.h) (github link) as a `UIView` containing several buttons. You could do the same with a space between buttons.

Then I added that as a single button item with a custom view.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(320-width, 0, width, height);
[segControl.view setFrame:frame];
segControl.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segControl.view];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;
```

The result is able to expand closer to the middle:

[image]

Answering the comment below: yes, it's independent.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution. Does the segmented control still align properly if you have a much longer title than *Jobs* on your previous button?

Comment: Can you post the code you used to create the three buttons? Your approach is great but having the complete code could be useful? is it on github?

Comment: Yes, it's linked in the first line of the answer.

Comment: The segmented control has its own nib and view controller. The view controller is SegControlVC: https://github.com/j4n0/jobsket/blob/master/sources/main/ui/search/jobs/SearchJobsTVC.m The class FavoritesDetailTVC adds the segmented control at line 390 and implements the delegate at line 464 https://github.com/j4n0/jobsket/blob/master/sources/main/ui/favorites/detail/FavoritesDetailTVC.m#L464 The graphic for the buttons is in the nib SearchJobsTVC.xib The segmented control itself is at https://github.com/j4n0/jobsket/blob/master/sources/main/ui/search/jobs/detail/SegControlVC.h

Comment: I used your code to obtain a little different results to make two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

What's your deadline? This functionality is added in iOS5, so if you're going to release your app after (correct me if I'm wrong) september you can switch your app to the new UIKit. You will lose backwards-compability to <= iOS4 though.

Comment: You are true, I didn't noticed that. But I could need to do this before iOS 5

Comment: Could I ask a question? What class in UIKit the new feature added in for this case ?

Comment: Besides `UINavigationBar.leftBarButtonItem` there's also `UINavigationItem.leftBarButtonItems` in iOS5 (note the *s*).

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIToolbar *tool = [UIToolbar new];
    tool.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 42);
    //tool.frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;   
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:7];
    //space

    UIBarButtonItem *btn3;
     btn3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
     UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace   target:nil action:nil];
     [items addObject:btn3];
     [btn3 release];


    //create setting button
    UIButton *bttn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 0, 20, 30)];
    [bttn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [bttn addTarget:self action:@selector(settings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    UIBarButtonItem *btn1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:bttn];
    [items addObject:btn1];
    [btn1 release];


    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];

    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
           UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace   target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];


    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
           UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace   target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];
    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
           UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace   target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];

    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
           UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace   target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];

    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
           UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace   target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];



    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
           UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace   target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];



    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
               UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace   target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];

    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
           UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace   target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];


    //pause Button
    UIButton *bttn1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 30)];
    [bttn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [bttn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(pause:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    //UIBarButtonItem *btn2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:bttn1];
    btnPause = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:bttn1];
    [items addObject:btnPause];
    //[btn2 release];

    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
                               UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];

    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
           UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];
    //Space
    btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
           UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:btn];
    [btn release];

    //Next Button
    btnNext = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
               UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay  target:self action:@selector(next:)];
    [items addObject:btnNext];


    [tool setItems:items];
    tool.barStyle =UIBarStyleDefault;
    tool.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView = tool;
    //self.navigationItem.titleView = tool;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tool];
```

use this method to display more buttons in toolbar with navigation.

Comment: What's the need for eleven *flexible space* buttons? There's a very good reason it's called *flexible space*.

Comment: but I need the left button as well :-(

Comment: i show the way now you can get help from this code.I don't have any idea what u will doing?