# How to add UISegmentControl in UINavigationItem ..?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

How do I add `UISegmentedControl` in `UINavigationItem`?
I want to create a `UINavigationBar` with segment control which add in title of navigation bar.

`UISegmentedControl` has two indexes.

Here's what I have:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grid.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"],nil]];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 40);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    segmentedControl.momentary = YES;
    [segmentedControl setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];    
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
```

I had put it in right side. So, also want to put in middle of navigation bar.

This does not work please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Thanks

Comment: One way to do it is using this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828270/uinavigationbar-with-two-buttons-on-the-left/6828577#6828577 and changing the origin of the frame so it starts in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to add the segmented control to a UINavigationItem and add that to your UINavigationBar:

```
// This code is used for a custom navigation bar

UINavigationItem* newItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
[newItem setTitleView:segmentedControl];

// Assuming you already have a navigation bar called "navigationBar"
[navigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newItem] animated:NO];

// No memory leaks please...
[newItem release];
```

or if you want to use an existing controller

```
// This is used for an existing navigation controller
[navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:segmentedControl];
// or if you want to access through the root view controller of the nav controller
[rootController.navigationItem setTitleView:segmentedControl];
```

That should set the center view of your navigation bar to the segmented control.

Hope I could help!

EDIT: If you need more help, the Apple documentation of these classes is quite thorough:

[UINavigationItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationItem)

[UINavigationBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)

Comment: My class already Navigation base class.. SO it gives error like this      'Cannot call setItems:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'...

Comment: I added code to support an existing navigation controller. Let me know how it works.

Comment: see this link..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828270/uinavigationbar-with-two-buttons-on-the-left/6828577#6828577 NOW IT WORKS