# Tabbed UIBarButtonItem used in UIToolbar of iOS Phone app

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem

Which is the UIBarButtonItem used in the Recent calls view of the Phone app?

[image: Screenshot]

It doesn't look like a public API I know of. How can I create a similar UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850204/how-to-add-uisegmentcontrol-in-uinavigationitem

Comment: @Jitesh, thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I'll mark my question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can add **Segment** controller into **UIToolBar**. So it looks like as you want.

Cheeerrs

Comment: ya you are right man :)

Comment: I'm looking into this, thanks. I need to get an integrated appearance to the UISegmentedControl, rather than the default gray background.

Comment: @VinodVishwanath please accept this answer so its use for someone else :)

Comment: @Rushabh, I don't believe this is a complete answer. 2 other answers also point to UISegmentedControl, but the important piece was setting the segmented control's style to `UISegmentedControlStyleBar`. I've marked my question as a duplicate to another question that provides the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is done by something like below, no public api is used..

```
UIToolbar *toolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"All",@"Missed", nil]];
self.navigationItem.titleView=toolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
NSArray *segItemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"All", @"Missed", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segItemsArray];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    NSArray *barArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: flexibleSpace,segmentedControl, nil];
     [toolbar setItems:barArray];
```

Comment: What is flexible space here? How does the toolbar connected with the UISegmentedControl?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Got my answer. I just have to set `toolbar.titleView` to the segmentedControl, and it should have the style `UISegmentedControlStyleBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

> Add **UISegmentedControl** to an **UIToolBar**

Option 2: (in case you are using a navigation controller)

> Add **UISegementControl** to an **UINavigationBar**