# Multiple buttons on Navigation Bar in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know there is a lot on this topic but I can't get any code to work. I'm running iOS5 and building for the iPad and I just can't get two buttons on one side of my navigation bar.

### Edit

Some code I have tested, its in `viewDidLoad`, doesn't do anything though.

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(save)];

    UIBarButtonItem *deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(delete)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:saveButton,deleteButton,nil];
```

Comment: Can you post what you have so far? Here's an example of using a segmented control: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6828577/1264925

Comment: That code should be working, have you tried putting those buttons on the screen somewhere else?  like setting the left barbutton item, and right barbutton item to those so you can see if they are being created properly?

Comment: Hmm, nope, no success. I am using a stand UIViewController if that makes any difference, I don't need to include specific delegates do I?

Comment: Im assuming your view is actually embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: Dan F, what does it mean tah view is actually embedded. I've got the same problem like Josh

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In iOS 5 the `UINavigationItem` gained the array properties: `rightBarButtonItems` and `leftBarButtonItems`.  You can see more details about how they work in relation to `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem` and the back button [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) in the class reference.

In short, you just make an array out of your buttons, and set the navigation item's properties as such. I have used this feature to have two buttons on both the left and right of my navigation bar.

**EDIT**

Here's the code I used to create my arrays.  My buttons were all created in interface builder:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:backButton, settingsButton, nil];
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:continueButton, saveButton, nil];
```

Comment: Is it as easy as that or am I missing something? I have made two `UIBarButtonItems`, added them to an array and set `rightBarButtonItems` to my array, but nothing.

Comment: It should be that simple, do you have some code for how the buttons are being created, the array is being created, and how you're assigning it to the `rightBarButotnItems` property?

Answer (score 0):

I believe these answers assume you're using the default navigation bar. (In other words, the one that iOS gives you "for free" when you use a UINavigationViewController.)

If you're using a custom UINavigationBar, then you'll need to retrieve it's first UINavigationItem. (You can also overwrite the default UINavigationItem.) From there, you can set the leftBarButtonItems and rightBarButtonItems properties.

Something like this:

```
// customNavBar points to my custom UINavigationBar
navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Details"];
NSArray *navArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:navItem, nil];
[customNavBar setItems:navArray];  // This wipes out all existing UINavigationItem objects

NSArray *leftArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:itemOk, nil];
NSArray *rightArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:itemCancel, nil];
navItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftArray;
navItem.rightBarButtonItems= rightArray;
```